# subbasis for a topology Munkres

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about the following definition: 
A **subbasis** $S$ for a topology on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$. The **topology generated by the subbasis** $S$ is defined to be the collection $T$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$. 
If you have a subbasis $S$ for a topology $A$, then is the topology generated by $S$ necessarily also $A$? It seems like you could have many different subbases for $A$, but my intuition is that they might not all generate the same topology $A$. Is there something i'm missing? Thanks for any help/clarification.

Sincerely,

Vien

Comment: The definition you gave starts from the subbasis $S$, then generates the topology $T$ from it. If you say that $S$ is a subbasis of $A$, it means $A$ is a topology, and it is generated by $S$.

Comment: Echoing @Tunococ, if $S$ is a subbasis for the topology $A$, then, by definition, $A = \sigma(S)$.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers. Funny thing, as i look through the internet, i'm finding a couple slightly different looking definitions of subbasis from the one in my book...

Comment: @Vien [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138089/base-and-subbase-of-a-topology) seems to be related.

Comment: Maybe you could list the different definitions in your question (or possibly post them as an answer). It would be beneficial for both future readers of this thread and yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other definitions that are equivalent:

Let $X$ be a topological space with topology $\tau$. A subbase of $\tau$ is usually defined as a subcollection $\mathcal{B}$ of $\tau$ satisfying one of the two following equivalent conditions:

1. The subcollection $\mathcal{B}$ generates the topology $\tau$.
   *[This means that T is the smallest topology containing B: any topology U on X containing B must also contain T.]*
2. The collection of open sets consisting of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, together with the set $X$ and the empty set, forms a basis for $\tau$.
   *[This means that every non-empty proper open set in T can be written as a union of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. Explicitly, given a point x in a proper open set $U$, there are finitely many sets $S_1, \dots, S_n \in \mathcal{B}$, such that the intersection of these sets contains $x$ and is contained in $U$. (wiki)]*

A collection of subsets of a topological space that is contained in a basis of the topology and can be completed to a basis when adding all finite intersections of the subsets. (wolfram mathworld)

Comment: Wikipedia explicitely says that these two definitions you are giving are not equivalent to the one in Munkres book https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase